# PERMANOVA on categorical data set

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I am trying to perform a multivariate analysis using R and as I have a ecololgical dataset of categorical data only, is it possible to use PERMANOVA on this type of dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `adonis`{vegan} help page, your predictors variables can be continuous or factors.  The response variables (Y) must be a dissimilarity matrix. So then I would say that because you can make a dissimilarity matrix based on categorical data (for example, using the `daisy` function in {cluster}), it is possible to use categorical data as the response.

I would recommend reading [this paper](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.esajournals.org%2Fdoi%2Fpdf%2F10.1890%2F12-2010.1&ei=vhpqVO_sJs-tyAS744GQDw&usg=AFQjCNHKn9TN1ieU7MMzoeLqOk966thT9Q&sig2=sF-LcFXIJrQFqAvhzylM8A&bvm=bv.79142246,d.aWw) by Anderson and Walsh (2013) on testing the null hypothesis in perMANOVA, ANOSIM and the Mantel test.